# Last login information to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know the last login information of all the users i.e. I need to know the details when the user last logged into the MySQL database.
I need to do this from the SQL query and not by connecting to the server or via command prompt(I know we can see these details in General log but I need from the SQL query).

I checked under mysql.user table but didn't found anything relevant to the date time or login activity. Do we have any such tables in MySQL that stores the last login details?

I checked couple of post wherein the user has created a table(eg. : last_login table) but I don't find them complete and some of them are related to the PHP Admin. What I want here is the login information to the MySQL database and not to the application.

MySQL version : 5.7.21-log.

Edit : General log is disabled for some reasons so is there any way to check the login information now with SQL queries?

Comment: Need to enable general query log in order to be able to track. I doubt if you can get data retrospectively now. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya : Enabling general log will save the login details in the general.log file. Suppose general log is enabled then how can we check the last login information from the MySQL GUI since I don't have the server access and I need to fetch those details from MySQL query.

Comment: There is an option to save to a table also. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/log-destinations.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya : I won't be able to enable the general log as I am not supposed to do the same. Can you tell me any alternate solution like tables creation or any tables present in the mysql?

Comment: I doubt if there is any other MySQL only solution possible. Another way is to do logging in your application code (eg: PHP) However this will not be able to log direct connections made to the MySQL server